# Call Dart Function from android service

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am still new with flutter plugins development and method channels.
I have this function in my flutter code that shows a pop up window

```
void _showOverlayWindow() {
    if (!_isShowingWindow) {
      SystemWindowHeader header = SystemWindowHeader(...);
      SystemWindowBody body = SystemWindowBody(...);
      SystemWindowFooter footer = SystemWindowFooter(...);
      SystemAlertWindow.showSystemWindow(...);
    }
  }
```

and in my java code I have a brodcast receiver that triggers on some event

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d("MYTAG","Sent from brodcast receiver");

    }
}
```

the receiver works on it's own, now I'd like to know if it's possible to run my flutter function that shows the pop up from the java side. Currently I am able to run the app through the receiver as follows

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d("MYTAG","Sent from brodcast receiver");

      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setClassName("com.example.myApp","com.example.myApp.MainActivity");
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      ctx.startActivity(i);
}
```

but I was wondering if it possible to run only that function, just showing the pop up without the app screen view, and if it is possible, does that mean I still have to load the whole app? because the function depends on other states in the class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the background color to `transparent`, you can see the view still has a black background because of the default setting of the Android app theme. You need to modify the config to achieve total transparent, which is:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Then adding transparent to the launching intent here:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.BackgroundMode.transparent
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        intent.putExtra("background_mode", transparent.toString())
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

You can look at a simple example with only a `Dialog` display on the screen here: https://github.com/NMateu/flutter_transparent_app

You can look into these projects that implement background running:

- From the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)
- Android Alarm Manager: https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager
- Background Location: https://pub.dev/packages/background_location

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo) is a good guide on Flutter background service as well

Comment: Thanks, this partially solves the problem, this works if I only want the pop up, but I want the pop up to show when the event occurs, but I also want to have other functionalities in the app. In other words, when I open the app manually I want to show the app normally, but when the event happens while the app is closed, I want to show the pop up only

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib It's possible to run Dart code in background and listening to events. You can explore the config of the open-source packages I included in the answer to understand more about that:

Comment: one last question, I was concerned about showing some ui like the pop up from the background, because I only see people running dart code from the background which excutes some non ui functionalities.

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib I think the best way is to explore local notification rather than Dialog display. This way the FlutterLocalNotifications will be able to start your UI when the notification is interacted.

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib Btw can you choose an answer to mark as an accepted answer. Would appreciate it man!